# Background repeat image to animate in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to work with Tailwind CSS, where currently now I am trying to animate a background image. I tried different methods but have not yet figured out how to animate the background image in single direction from left to right.

Here is what I have done so far.

- Added a custom background image
- Added a repeat so that it fills the area.

What additionally I want to do, is show it like an animation, so it feels like it's moving. I had already implemented it in normal CSS but can't put it in Tailwind.

Following is the video for the animation that has been achieved in normal CSS: https://youtu.be/Jx8fg2MdG3Y

Following is the Tailwind playground for the background I have implemented so far: https://play.tailwindcss.com/jmoPHTdXAe

Current implemented code in Tailwind.

```
<div class="p-6 bg-gray-500 flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen justify-center bg-hero-pattern bg-repeat animate-ltr-linear-infinite">
<div class="text-white">
    <h1 class="text-6xl">Some Text HERE</h1>
    <h1 class="text-2xl">Background Not Animating</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

The following is the configuration I have tried so far in Tailwind.

```
  theme: {
    extend:{
      backgroundImage: theme => ({
        'hero-pattern': "url('img/bg.png')"
      }),
      animation:{
        'ltr-linear-infinite': 'normal 100s linear infinite'
      }
    }
  }
```

Following is the image I am using for repeat:

https://i.ibb.co/Qn5BR8N/bg.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

I couldn't see animation in your code. I see just the "timing-function".
Writing this:

```js
animation: {
  'ltr-linear-infinite': 'normal 100s linear infinite'
}
```

You tell Tailwind what he should define animation class like this:

```css
.ltr-linear-infinite {
  animation: normal 100s linear infinite;
}
```

It of course wouldn't work properly — there is no `@keyframes normal`.

---

#### The solution

Citation from [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation):

> To add new animation `@keyframes`, use the `keyframes` section of your theme configuration:
>
> ```js
> // tailwind.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   theme: {
>     extend: {
>       keyframes: {
>         wiggle: {
>           '0%, 100%': { transform: 'rotate(-3deg)' },
>           '50%': { transform: 'rotate(3deg)' },
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

So, in your case it would be like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // Define pattern
      backgroundImage: theme => ({
        'hero-pattern': "url('img/bg.png')"
      }),
      // Define animation class
      animation: {
        'ltr-linear-infinite': 'move-bg 10s linear infinite',
      },
      // Define keyframes
      keyframes: {
        'move-bg': {
          '0%':   { 'background-position': '0 0' },
          '100%': { 'background-position': '256px 0'}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*P.S. `100s` makes background to move `~2.5px/s`. Perhaps it is too slow, so I changed it to `~25px/s`.*

Comment: Thankyou, only a minute or two before i had figured the solution out. But your code seems a bit more better, will use yours.

Thanks again. I had also modified it a bit.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/d825A4Se3Z

Comment: This was helpful for recreating [bootstrap's animated stripes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/progress/#animated-stripes) on a progress bar, as in `progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add keyframes in the configuration of tailwind as well. to make it work.

following is the Working [EXAMPLE](https://play.tailwindcss.com/D11bWsXnZW)

This is the updated code for reference if anyone needs in future.

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        'hero-pattern': "url('https://i.ibb.co/Qn5BR8N/bg.png')",
      }),
      animation: {
        'ltr-linear-infinite': 'ltr-linear-infinite 100s linear infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        'ltr-linear-infinite': {
          'from': { 'background-position': '0 0' },
          'to': { 'background-position': '400% 0%' },
        },
      },
    }
  }
```